# How to detect how many pings are in a message DISCORD JS?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

How can I detect how many pings are in a message?
I'm not sure where to start. I'm trying to create a anti-raid bot and I want to detect if someone pings 5 people in one message

Answer (score 1):

[MessageMentions#user](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageMentions?scrollTo=users) returns a discord.js collection, you can get the length of the collection by simply using `message.mentions.users.size`, this works with any mentions like

- .roles
- .members
- .channels

and you can just detect using

```js
if(message.mentions.members.size > n) {
  message.delete();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple code that counts **unique** user mentions in the message.

```js
let count = 0;
for(const user of msg.mentions.users) {
    count++;
}
if(count>4) {
    msg.delete();
}
```

Comment: This is a bit redundant. There is no point in looping through everything over just using `Array.from(msg.mentions.users).length-1`

Answer (score 0):

<s>You can see how many people were pinged using `message.mentions.users` Like the following:</s>

```js
Array.from(message.mentions.users).length
```

It may be 1 over what you need, because Javascript strings start at 0. If so, just add a -1.

```js
Array.from(message.mentions.users).length-1
```

And please, search this stuff up. I was able to find this on the Discord.js [documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageMentions) in a matter of seconds.

Me being stupid again, use `size` attribute on `message.mentions.users` collection per the [Keyed Collection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Keyed_collections) standard.